# Vue axios error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 415

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I hope you all are well!

I have a error in vue axios

```js
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 415
```

Here's my code

```js
authService.Login(user)
          .then(resp => {
            if (resp.data.success) {
              resolve(resp)
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
          })
```

```js
Login (data) {
    return shaxios.post('api/Auth/Authorize', data)
  }
```

Comment: The error comes from the backend. Currently you're the only person who can debug it. Also this `if (resp.data.success) {
              resolve(resp)` is a mistake, this will result in pending promise if the condition is false. This is promise construction antipattern. An existing promise shouldn't be wrapped with `new Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

You may send a JSON object to an API expecting a Form URL-encoded HTTP POST request.

Have you checked https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded ?